# Unity get collision coordinate with hidden part of a plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a sphere on a plane that stick to my mouse. i want to place that sphere so the position of the pointer, where the pointer would hit the plane. But the plane is hidden by the ball. It works, but the movement of the ball is noisy.
i would like to ignore everything except the plane for the collision.
can anyone help ?

This is what i do actually:

```
if (Ball!= null) {
        RaycastHit raycastHit;
        
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit, 100f))
        {
            if (raycastHit.transform != null)
            {
                //Our custom method. 
                var x = raycastHit.point.x;
                var z = raycastHit.point.z;
                Ball.pos().get_x().update_value(x);
                Ball.pos().get_z().update_value(z);
                
            }
        }
        
        }
```

Comment: You should use the layer mask parameter and make sure that your Raycast can only hit one layer - the layer you will assign your plane to

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the Layers & Layer Masks. Create a new layer and name it MyHiddenLayer and assign your object to it. Then do:

```
// Define output
RaycastHit raycastHit;

// Define Ray
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

// Define Layer
int layerMask = 1 <<  LayerMask.NameToLayer("MyHiddenLayer");

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out raycastHit, 100f, layerMask))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah don't do it that way .. really use a `public LayerMask layerMask;` and configure it via the Inspector ;)

Comment: @derHugo why not do it that way?

Comment: @MrMoonMan because it's error prone and hardcoded ... using und configuring a `LayerMask` in the Inspector is more flexible, easy to adjust and extend and not open for typos and non-existent layer names